# Er hat die Natur mögen

Tags: austrian, bavarian

Heute auf der Website einer österreichischen Zeitung gesehen. Diese Konstruktion ist mir nicht gänzlich fremd, ich frage mich nur gerade ob so etwas auch in Bayern gängig ist. Google war hier mal ausnahmsweise nicht mein Freund. Gibt's dazu vielleicht was auf einer Website oder in der Literatur?

Kontext: https://derstandard.at/2000101737583/Messner-Schlimmes-Unglueck

> Später habe Lama dann den Übergang von den Kletterhallen in die freie
>   Wildnis, zum traditionellen Bergsteigen geschafft: "**Er hat die Natur
>   mögen**. Die mögen ja auch nicht alle. Er wurde ein Vorbild für viele.
>   David war ein humorvoller, ruhiger Mensch. Ich habe ihn über alle
>   Maßen geschätzt".

Comment: Willkommen auf German SX. Ich (aus Norddeutschland) kenne die Konstruktion nicht und weiß auch nicht, was sie heißen soll (Er mag / mochte die Natur?). Ist sie ein abgeschlossener Satz? Könntest du den Link zum Artikel (falls online gesehen) posten, oder zumindest etwas Kontext hinzufügen?

Comment: _Gemocht_ ist wohl die hochdeutsche Form. Aber diese Ausdrucksweise ist mir zumindest nicht fremd (bin Bayer).

Comment: @Philipp Ihr norddeusche habt keine Ahnung von der Subtilität die der süddeutsche Dialekt so bietet.

Comment: Kontext hinzugefügt.

Comment: Es erinnert mich an das Sprachspiel von Wolf Haas ein bissel. Und das ist richtig _cool_. Norddeutsche haben keine Ahnung.

Comment: Du solltest in deiner Frage bitte auch abgeben, was du stattdessen erwartet hättest. Ich bin Österreicher und finde daran überhaupt nichts ungewöhnliches. Erst als ich die Antwort von David Vogel gelesen habe, wurde mir klar, dass es um das Wort *»mögen«* geht, das offenbar anderswo durch *»gemocht«* ersetzt wird (was in meinen Ohren aber sehr unsympatisch klingt).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Beide Formen, sowohl *»gemocht«* als auch *»mögen«*, sind hochdeutsch. Man kann beide sowohl in Tageszeitungen aus auch in amtlichen Dokumenten finden, und beide werden in Schulaufsätzen als korrekt anerkannt und werden in Schulen auch genau so unterrichtet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laut [dieser Karte](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f10a-e/) des *Atlas zur  deutschen Alltagssprache* ist der unerwartete Ersatzinfinitiv – unerwartet, da kein weiterer Infinitiv von ihm abhängt — im gesamten oberdeutschen Gebiet, etwa bis zur Höhe von Stuttgart, üblich.

[[image: 1]]

Comment: Sehr interessant, da das Süddeutsche den Ersatzinfinitiv ja sonst nicht verwendet.

Comment: Das wäre mir neu. Belege in [dieser Dissertation](https://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/000528), S. 133-36.

Answer (score 3):

Zum Grenzverlauf kann ich nicht viel sagen. Ich kann aber ergänzen, dass zumindest im Osten Österreichs der Ersatzinfinitiv sehr oft gegenüber dem Partizip II bevorzugt wird:

Bei den Modalverben wird das Partizip II in Österreich so gut wie gar nicht verwendet:

> Es tut ihm leid, er hat das wirklich nicht <del>*gewollt*</del> **wollen.**
>   Erika war verzweifelt, denn sie hat nicht zu Jürgen <del>*gedurft*</del> **dürfen.**
>   Simon hat es ehrlich versucht, aber er hat es dann doch nicht <del>*gekonnt*</del> **können.**
>   Warum hat Willi keine Eier mitgebracht? Eigentlich hätte er das <del>*gesollt*</del> **sollen.**
>   Ich hasse es, Honigmilch zu trinken. Als Kind habe ich das immer <del>*gemusst*</del> **müssen.**
>   Er hat die Natur <del>*gemocht*</del> **mögen.**

Aber auch bei einigen anderen Verben ziehen wir den Ersatzinfinitiv vor:

> Ich finde meine Schlüssel nicht. Ich habe sie wohl im Büro liegen <del>*gelassen*</del> **lassen.**
>   Wir wollten es nicht, aber wir haben Stefan tanzen <del>*gesehen*</del> **sehen.**
>   Vor ein paar Wochen haben wir ihn auch Blockflöte spielen <del>*gehört*</del> **hören.**

Ich habe zwar bisher geglaubt, dass das im gesamten Sprachraum so ist, aber die Existenz der hier gestellten Frage beweist, dass das nicht der Fall ist. Ich glaube aber auch, dass die geographischen Grenzen bei jedem Verb woanders liegen. Ich kann mir beispielsweise nicht vorstellen, dass es irgendeine Region gibt, in der es üblich ist, *»er hätte Eier mitbringen gesollt«* zu sagen.

Comment: Es liegt nicht nur am Verb, sondern auch an dessen Verwendung. In den Beispielen in deinem zweiten Block ist die Verwendung als Modalverb, da benutze ich auch den Ersatzinfinitiv.

Comment: "Sie hat nicht zu Jürgen dürfen." would pass in my northern german idiolect as well.

Comment: Für die drei Beispiele aus dem zweiten Zitatblock scheint Berlin wohl auf der Grenze zu liegen, denn mir sind beide Varianten vertraut, wobei ich vom Stil her die Formen gesehen und gehört, aber lassen leicht bevorzugen würde. Im ersten Kasten sind durchweg die durchgestrichenen Varianten die, die für mich natürlich klingen.