# Fetzen im Sinne von betrunken - Herkunft/Austriazismus

Tags: etymology, austrian, bavarian

Durch Zufall stieß ich auf den Ausdruck *Fetzen* mit einer mir bislang unbekannten Bedeutung, der anscheinend in Österreich, evtl. auch in [Bayern](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/bayern/kulturgeschichte-des-saufens-abkehr-vom-saurausch-1.3121469) verbreitet ist und wohl seit mindestens Mitte des 19. Jhd. existiert.

> Fetzen → ugs. derb Betrunkenheit/Rausch

[1](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fetzen), [2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Austriazismen#F)

bzw.

> einen Fetzen haben → betrunken sein

[3](http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-213-einen_Fetzen_haben-betrunken_sein.html)

**Woher kommt diese Bedeutung im Österreichischen?**

[DWDS](https://m.dwds.de/wb/Fetzen), [Wiktionary](https://m.dwds.de/wb/Fetzen), [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=fetzen) oder andere Online-Quellen brachten mir keine wirkliche Erklärung.

**Zusatzfrage:**

Besteht ein Zusammenhang mit dem Austriazismus von Fetzen für die [Schulnote 5](http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-9097-Schulnote_5-Fetzen.html)?

Comment: Für die Verwendung in Österreich bzw. gar der Quelle habe ich nichts. Ich weiß nur: in Studentenverbindungen u.ä. gibt es die Tradition des Salamander reibens, wo der "Reibende" sich danach bedankt und als Abschluss "einen gehörigen Fetzen reißt = sein Bier leert" (Magdeburger Biercomment, unter IV $28, https://www.ottonia-magdeburg.de/Dokumente/Comment.html#a14) - d.h., falls Kommers = rituelles Besäufnis, dann Fetzen = Grundlage zum betrunken sein.

Comment: Das ist nicht auf bairische Dialekte beschränkt. Auch allemannische Dialekte (schwäbisch, badisch) kennen den Ausdruck "der hat einen Fetzen im Gesicht"

Comment: Seit unzähligen Generationen erzählt man über den jeweils amtierenden Bürgermeister von Wien den folgenden Witz: "Warum ist der Rathausplatz so sauber? Weil der ______ jeden Tag mit dem Fetzen drübergeht."

Comment: @tofro Danke für den Hinweis, aber irgendwie finde ich dafür keine Beispiele.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Die Beschreibung sagt "Und nun sei es auch mir gestattet, einen gehörigen Fetzen aus diesem Stoffe zu reißen." Wobei Stoff laut §8 Bier ist (muss da irgendwie an Werners Bölkstoff denken). Wäre eine mögliche Erklärung für den Ausdruck. Den Ausdruck fand ich so zwar nicht nochmal, aber bei Burschenschaften scheint es allgemein "commentgemäße Stoffe" zu geben. Wenn der Ausdruck älter ist, könnte ein Zusammenhang bestehen.

Comment: @sgf: Die Redewendung vom Wiener Bürgermeister ist mir nur in Bezug auf Helmut Zilk und Michael Häupl geläufig, weil beide bekannt dafür waren, gerne tief ins Glas geschaut zu haben. In Bezug auf den amtierenden Bürgermeister Michael Ludwig habe ich das noch nicht gehört. Er ist noch nicht lange genug im Amt, um sich diesen Ruf erarbeitet zu haben. Zum Spruch selbst ist zu ergänzen, dass das Wort "drübergehen" für "putzen" in Österreich wenig gebräuchlich ist. Ich kenne den Spruch so: »Warum ist Wien so eine saubere Stadt? Weil der Zilk/Häupl jeden Tag mit einem Fetzen durch die Stadt geht.«

Comment: @tofro: Die Karte mit der geographischen Verteilung der Bekanntheit des Begriffs spricht eher gegen deine Behauptung: http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-213-einen_Fetzen_haben-betrunken_sein.html

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Es hätte mich auch gewundert, wenn ein *österreichisches Wörterbuch*  sich über südwestdeutsche Dialekte auslassen würde. Man sagt im Schwäbischen auch nicht "einen Fetzen haben", sondern "einen Fetzen im Gesicht haben"

Comment: @mtwde Siehe z.B. hier:http://schwaebisches-woerterbuch.de/default.asp?q=Fetza unter "Kommentare" schauen (der ist nicht von mir).

Comment: @mtwde: mein kleiner Einblick in die Kommerswelt ist zu groß für den Kommentar. Kurz gesagt: ja, es braucht commers/commentfähige Stoffe, idR Bier (wird vom Präsidium festgelegt). "diesem Stoffe" = der kommersfähige Stoff, auch 'der edle Stoff', aus dem man einen Fetzen reißt = großen Schluck trinkt.

Answer (score 2):

Was ich im DWB und den mit ihm vernetzten Wörterbüchern gefunden habe:

> [pfetzen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=pfetzen) "zwicken, kneifen"
>   *sie machen ihn den mundt ganz englisch halten, so gezogen und gepfetzt* (gezerrt).

Von dort wird verwiesen auf:

> [petzen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=petzen)
>   leipz. *petschen*, hörbar kauen Albrecht 181b; darmstädtisch *petschen*, trinken (vgl. *kneipen*): *ich wor bei e poor gute freind, un do howwe mer e scheppche wei minnanner gepetzt.*

Man beachte den Verweis auf die ähnliche wörtliche und übertragene Bedeutung von:

> [kneipen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=kneipen)
>   4) *kneipen* zu *kneipe* 3, *kneipschenke* gehörig, sowol ins wirtshaus gehn als besonders im wirtshaus sitzen und zechen. es ist noch bei Heyse nicht genannt und scheint aus nd. mundarten emporgekommen, wo trinken ausgedrückt wird mit *ênen knîpen, sik ênen knîpen*.

(*Kneifen* ist verschobenes *kneipen*.)

Zurück zu *fetzen, petzen, pfetzen*. Aus dem Pfälzischen Wörterbuch:

> [Fetzen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/PfWB?lemma=fetzen)
>   4. c. "totaler Rausch". *Wie kammer sich so e F. hole!*

(Das hat auch [Fetzer](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/PfWB?lemma=fetzer) "Trinker").

Das Wörterbuch der elsässischen Mundarten:

> [pfëtzeⁿ](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/ElsWB?lemma=pfetzen)
>   6. trinken. *Kumm, mⁱr wëˡˡen geʰⁿ, eⁱneⁿ Schoppeⁿ p.!*

Und schließlich nochmal das Pfälzische Wörterbuch:

> [pfetzen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/PfWB?lemma=pfetzen)
>   6. *e Schoppe* (Wein), *de Korze* (einen Schnaps) *petze* "trinken", eigentl. "den Schluck mit zusammengekniffenen Lippen prüfen, genießerisch trinken"

Das paßt wunderbar zu dem ersten genannten Lemma, *pfetzen* im DWB. Das Bild, daß sich mir bietet, ist, daß in vielen deutschen Dialekten ein Wort, daß *kneifen, zwicken* bedeutet, wie etwa *petzen, pfetzen, fetzen, petschen*; *kneipen*, die Bedeutung "(Alkohol) trinken" angenommen hat, möglicherweise vermittelt durch das Bild der zusammengekniffenen Lippen, die *prüfen, genießerisch trinken*.

Die Einordnung des von *p(f)etzen* stammenden *Fetzen* unter dem Wort, das "Lumpen" bedeutet, wäre dann ein Fehler.

Comment: https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/pietschen ist wahrscheinlich auch damit verwandt

Comment: "das Bild der zusammengekniffenen Lippen" ist wenig überzeugend. Wenn überhaupt denke ich dabei an ein schmerzverziertes Gesicht und selbst das erscheint mir zu weit hergeholt. Es wäre wohl einfacher nebenan bei den slaven zu schauen, wo \*piti- einfach "trinken" bedeutet, abgeleitet von PIE \*peh3-, vgl. Gujarati *pivu*, während Polnisch *pivo* für Bier steht, so wie Italienisch *bere* widerum für flüssige Nahrungsaufnahme. Auch *Pfütze* könnte hier stehen. Der Vergleich zu *kneip-* ist natürlich nicht ganz von der Hand zubweisen, vgl das *schnippische Grinsen* im Gesicht. *puddelwohl fühlen*

Answer (score 1):

Es dürfte relativ einfach sein, den Begriff zu der für das Urindogermanische rekonstruierten Wurzel *peh3- mit der verbalerweiterung [*píph₃eti](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/p%C3%ADph%E2%82%83eti) "trinken" zu stellen, die in allen an den deutschen Sprachraum angrenzenden Sprachen reflektiert wird. IE *p wird nach der Ersten Großen Lautverschiebung bekanntlich zu *f, so dass es sich bei *fetzen* um eine Germanische Form handeln dürfte.

Die Phrase *fetzen haben* kann als missverstandene Nominalisierung aus der Verbform verstanden werden, da der irreguläre [Ersatzinfinitiv](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50770/er-hat-die-natur-m%c3%b6gen/50786?r=SearchResults#50786) "? Er hat fetzen" (=er hat gesoffen) ununterscheidbar ist von *Er hat Fetzen* (=Er hat Lumpen).

Dieser Ansatz wirft einige Fragen auf, die hier nicht abschließend geklärt werden.

---

Das Missverständnis ist vermutlich nicht aus gerader Linie entstanden, eben nicht dort, wo beide Formen, also das Wort sowie der Ersatzinfinitv geläufig gewesen sein mögen. Fraglich wäre zudem, ob keine verwanten Wortformen mit ähnlicher Bedeutung bezeugt sind.

Wie es zu einem Missverständnis kommen konnte, hängt mithin davon ab, worauf die neue Interpretation fußte. Das könnte nur aus einem weit angelegten Vergleich erschlossen werden, wenn nicht klar ist, wo und wann der Ursprung zu verorten ist. Ansatzweise bietet sich zum Vergleich einerseits "eine Fahne haben" <sup>1</sup>, andererseits "das fetzt" (das macht Spaß, da geht die Post ab), Fr. "fête" (Fest, Feier). Verharmlosende Wörter für Trunkenheit finden sich zur Genüge; Ich möchte "betüdelt" daraus hervorheben und En "tatters" (Lumpen, Fummel), "tassel" (Quaste), De "Zottel", "zotteln", "Tattergreiß", "zittern", "zerren" und etliches mehr vergleichen. Doch nachdem die rein zufälligen Ähnlichkeiten aussortiert werden (etwa "Zettel" vs "Fetzen", oder "petzen" vs En "tatter"; Beide mit Herleitung aus Latein [klassisches oder Mittelalter?]), bleibt nicht mehr viel.

Zum Ersatzinfinitiv bleibt anzumerken, dass Grimms Wörterbuch im Eintrag "stehen" recht deutlich hervorhebt, dass gerade das Perfekt-Partizip, das bei "fetzen haben" eben fehlt, die Wendung mit "haben" einst begünstigt hatte, also Norddeutsch "habe gestanden" vs Süddeutsch "war gestanden" u.ä.m.. Wie das in Relation zu partiziplosen Wendungen steht, eben "fetzen haben", habe ich bisher nicht erkennen können.

Der Fetzen, der in Burschenschaften gerissen wird, gesellt sich sicher zu "das Trinken, das Getränk" wie "Bier" zu Ita. "bere" (trinken).

Andere Worte für das Saufen--"trinken" ist eine scheinbar germanische Innovation, m.M.n. vergleichbar zu "Tränke" und Fr. "trench"--finden sich vielzälig. Darunter wäre zumindest Plattdeutsch(?) "picheln" wegen des Anlauts hervorzuheben, der aber doch nicht germanisch erscheint. En "booze", "buzzed" (Saufen; ein Ding zu sitzen haben, blau sein) vielen mir im Vergleich besonders auf, da "buzz" sonst als "Summen, Surren" gedeutet wird, lautlich aber in dieser Wendung zumindest auch zu den Trink-Worten gestellt werden könnte.

---

1: "Fahne haben": aus dem Mund nach Alkohol riechen, üblicher Weise wohl verstanden als *den Atem, der wie eine Fahne hinter sich herzieht, wie ein Signal vor sich hergetragen wird*; Interpretation meine. Vgl. auch Lat *fanum* "Tempel" und Wörter für "Brennen" (IE \dhegh-), s. *Brand haben* (Wassermangel nach übermäßigem Alkoholkonsum, der schnellst *gelöscht* werden muss und oft mit einem *Kater* (Rausch-bedingter Kopfschmerz) einher geht.